React: Ensuring Notification Appears Only Once After Successful Authentication Using query Parameters
I have a React component that handles authentication using query parameters from the URL. Upon successful authentication, a message should be displayed using an alert or notification system (in this case, message.success).
Initially, without any delay, the message can sometimes appear multiple times due to rapid updates in the component state. To prevent this, I added a flag (hasShowAuthSuccess.current) to ensure the message is shown only once per session of successful authentication.
Here's the initial code snippet:
if (query.get('success') === '1') {
  if (!hasShowAuthSuccess.current) {
    message.success('Authentication successful');
    hasShowAuthSuccess.current = true;
  }
}

However, the message still occasionally appears multiple times. To mitigate this issue, I introduced a setTimeout function with a delay of 1000 milliseconds before displaying the message. This approach seems to work better to ensure the message is shown only once after a successful authentication within the session.
Updated code snippet with setTimeout:
if (query.get('success') === '1') {
  if (!hasShowAuthSuccess.current) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      message.success('Authentication successful');
    }, 1000);
    hasShowAuthSuccess.current = true;
  }
}

Despite this solution, I'm curious about the best practice for handling such scenarios in React applications and why the first code snippet behaves like that. Is using setTimeout the recommended approach for ensuring a message appears only once, or are there alternative methods or patterns that could provide a more robust solution?


The message can sometimes appear multiple times due to rapid updates in the component state. To prevent this,

for that reason, you can use this useMemo hook (I guessing you are using react-router-dom)
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Main() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useSearchParams();
  const success = useMemo(() => query.get('success'), [query]);

  if (success === '1') {
    message.success('Authentication successful');
  }

  return <>test</>;
}

Make sure that you have disabled the strict mode in react.
 <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
 </React.StrictMode>

This will render the component twice in the development environment. Because of that, you can see two successful messages default.
